# I can't type '>' in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard

I am trying to solve problem with typing '>' character in Visual Studio. When I press the key nothing happens. The key works in all other applications, but not in Visual Studio.

I have tried install the Visual Studio 15 (the new test version), but even that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I had that happen to me once or twice in prerelease versions. Generally restarting VS fixed it.

Comment: It didnt work in the old Visual Studio too. I tried reinstalling it too.

Comment: So, what happens when you use the keyboard to type a "greater than" sign in Visual Studio?  What happens when you try to *paste* the same character, e.g. after copying from CharMap or other application?

Comment: When I try to write >, nothing happend. Copying work fine. < and , abd . work good too

Comment: Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard and click Reset then OK. Does that fix it?

Comment: okay, so I reset it and now I can see on the buttom when I press it : No quick actions available here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let me guess, you're using a non-English keyboard layout? One that uses *AltGr+.* for ">"?

The problem seems to be with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, which creates a key  shortcut for the *Ctrl+Alt+.* key combination. Resetting your settings will not help, since this is now one of the default shortcuts. Reinstalling or repairing your Visual Studio installation similarly won't help.

What you have to do is remove the problematic key shortcut - go to **Tools**, **Options**, **Environment**, **Keyboard**, search for command *"EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.QuickActionsForPosition"*. You will notice it's assigned to the *Ctrl+Alt+.* shortcut. Remove it and your ">" should once again work.

Answer (score 2):

You can reset your Environment Settings as said [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms247075(v=vs.90).aspx)

**To reset your settings**

1. On the **Tools** menu, click **Import and Export Settings**.
2. On the Welcome to the **Import and Export Settings Wizard** page, click **Reset all settings** and then click **Next**.
3. If you want to save your current settings combination, click **Yes, save my current settings**, specify a file name, and then click **Next**.

—or—

If you want to delete your current settings combination, choose **No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings**, and then click **Next**. This option does not delete default settings, which will still be available the next time you use the wizard.

4. In **Which collection of settings do you want to reset to**, select a settings collection from the list.
5. Click **Finish**.

The **Reset Complete** page alerts you to any problems encountered during the reset.

---

If the above still doesn't works, then follow this:

1. Press the ***Alt*** button from your keyboard and type in ***62*** from your **NUMPAD**

   `Alt` + 62

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio allows you to remap almost any key combination to any command. It's fairly easy to cause havoc by rebinding a commonly used key to something rather innocuous via the Tools > Options dialog:

[image: Pure Evil]

And given the sheer number of commands VS offers, trying to figure out which command it was bound to is nearly impossible is like searching for a needle in a haystack. The nuclear option is just to reset everything back to factory defaults (I assume that's okay with you since you've  tried re-installing). However, if you want a more surgical approach you can manually edit your settings (usually under `Documents\Visual Studio <X>\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings`) and look for a line like this:

```
<KeyboardShortcuts>
    <UserShortcuts>
        <Shortcut Command="Window.PinTab" Scope="Global">Shift+.</Shortcut>
    </UserShortcuts>
</KeyboardShortcuts>
```

And just remove it the shortcuts you'd like to get rid of. (You'll probably want to use an editor like Notepad++ that will reformat the XML for you to edit it more nicely). How this happened in the first place isn't clear. Unless you knew about this dialog to begin with, it's hard to see how you could have added this shortcut. I think someone may be playing a trick on you.